# Visit URL in running Firefox instance from command line in OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, firefox, window, browser-tabs

I have Firefox 3.6 installed on my OS X (10.6) box. I would like to open an URL in the running Firefox instance (in a new tab or window, no matter) from the command line. I tried several ways, neither switches `-new-tab`, `-new-window`, `-url`, or none helped me. I always get the *A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time.* error message.

Comment: The exact same thing is happening for me with the same setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

running

```
open http://www.superuser.com
```

from the command line will (at least for me) open a new tab to superuser.com in firefox (which is my default browser)

Comment: `open -a FireFox http://superuser.com` if you have a different default browser

Comment: @cobbal, though it will work whatever case you use, Firefox really just needs one uppercase F... :-)

Comment: Indeed, I think I've been using too much Objective-C, where everything is camelCased

Comment: @cobbal, bad ExCuse, not EveryThing is CamelCased. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in FireFox, since the [mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options) clearly states that for opening a website (from command line) under OS-X should be:

```
firefox -url www.google.com
```

The `-url` can be omitted, and the `-new-tab` switch added to force a new tab.

Comment: I just tried it under windows and "firefox.exe www.google.com" opens google in a new tab, in a running browser.

Comment: Yes, I know it *should* work the way you mentioned, but it doesn't for some reason.