# Firefox from command line not opening url in already running firefox on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, command-line, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visit URL in running Firefox instance from command line in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/113760/visit-url-in-running-firefox-instance-from-command-line-in-os-x)

I am running this command in Terminal.app

```
$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -new-tab www.ebay.com
```

In the case when Firefox is already open, i am getting the dialog as

*"A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time."*

I am expecting it to open the url in new tab in the already running version of Firefox.

What am I missing here? Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

The `-no-remote` argument tells it specifically not to do that, and to open a new instance. Get rid of that argument and it should work

Comment: hi 
Actually "$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -new-tab www.ebay.com" also gives the same result as previous :(